# How to prevent a user from accessing contact php page by writing URL?

Tags: php, url

I have made a simple contact form for my website with a validator, so users should enter alle inputs before the contact form can be submitted. After submission, the user is directed to a php page, i.e. all contact information will then be send to mail.
Unfortunately a user can bypass all the required inputs by just typing in the url of PHP. The result is an empty email.

How can i prevent users from going to the (succes submitted) PHP page by just typing in the PHP URL?

Comment: You can sit with users and shout at them when they try to enter the url.

Comment: You should probably reconsider your design. Use ajax post request. Or validate at the back-end. I'd say you should point a purpose why you care.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add some kind of check to your php file that sends the email:

```
if(!isset($_POST["someinput"]))
  exit; // don't continue if there is no input
```

A more appropriate error message should probably be used in production environments though.

Comment: Maybe just redirect to the form

Comment: If you do not necessary know in advance which inputs the form contains, you may check with this : `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') { exit; } else { /* logic here */ }` but no secured as someone may throw via Postman dumies values.

Comment: I am quite a noob with all this, sorry. But can i place if(!isset($_POST["someinput"]))
  exit; anywhere on the php file?

Comment: @co.do Before you send the mail, yes.

Comment: <?php 
/* Subject and Email Variables */
 $emailSubject = '';
 $webMaster = '';
 
/* Gathering Data Variables */

 $name = $_POST['Name'];
 $adress = $_POST['Address'];

 $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr<br>
Name: $name <br>
Address: $address <br>


EOD;
 $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
 $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
 $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);  
/* Results rendered as HTML */
 $theResults = <<<EOD
/*HTML option*/
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?> this is my kinda my php file. I tried to put If statement on top of file and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

In your php page check whether you get all post data or not.If you get all post data then only send email otherwise redirect user to  contact page.

Here is the logic:

```
if(!isset($_POST['Name']) && !empty($_POST['Name'])
!isset($_POST['Address']) && !empty($_POST['Address'])
)
{
    header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/contactus.php"); /* Redirect browser */
    exit();
}
else
{
 //send email
}
```